# Push notification from server to client using UDP

Tags: android, networking, https, push-notification, udp

We want to build a simple data sharing application where 2 Android mobiles (or computers) connected on any internet (wifi/network) upload and download their data to the server through HTTPS.

e.g. A wants to send data to B. A will trigger a "put" like HTTPS API and upload the data to the bucket of B. B will call the "get" like HTTPS API and download its content.

Now the issue is that the communication between A and B is demand based. It can happen after minutes, hours or days. If we go with HTTPS way, then we will have to keep B in a long polling to server which will eat out the resources for days when there is no message. If we poll every minute or 2 then the communication will not happen in near real time.

To counter this problem, we have come up with following idea:

1. Whenever mobile registers to internet, it creates a UDP port and
   binds to it
2. It makes 1 time HTTPS connection to server and sends its IP
   address and port
3. There can be optional dummy data exchange between server and client
   using UDP (to and from)
4. After this client doesn't have any active connection and remains
   on the same internet; It continuously waits on the UDP
   port for data to be received; If internet changes then again
   repeat from step-1
5. When data is received for the given client, then server sends
   some predefined dummy UDP data to client as a wake up call. This
   data is continuously sent until the client bucket is read via HTTPS
6. Upon identifying the data received on UDP, client makes an HTTPS
   connection to server and reads its intended data from its bucket and
   closes; Server identifies this and stops UDP

In theory this solution looks fine. But from internet I came across following problems for which I will require answers:

- What kind of IP address and port should be sent to server from
  client? Is it the ISP/network provided IP or something else?
- How server would identify the exact client to send some UDP data?
  e.g. if 2 mobiles on the same internet have same IP and ports
- In C socket library, there are 2 ways of UDP connections: (1)
  `connect()` and then just `send()/recv()` (2) Directly
  `sendto()`/`recvfrom()` using IP addresses. Which should be used in
  this scenario?

Besides above question, any improvement on the actual way of "push notification" described above is welcome.

Comment: Since the clients might not have a public IP you cannot use this kind of solution I'm afraid.

Comment: @Qiau, does that mean server to client UDP data is not possible? How the streaming/VoIP applications work in such case (from server to client)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to take care of clients behind NAT, for that you can use [UDP Hole Punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching).

> Let A and B be the two hosts, each in its own private network; NA and
>   NB are the two NAT devices with globally reachable IP addresses EIPA
>   and EIPB respectively; S is a public server with a well-known globally
>   reachable IP address.
>
> 1. A and B each begin a UDP conversation with S; the NAT devices NA and NB create UDP translation states and assign
>      temporary external port numbers EPA and EPB
> 2. S examines the UDP packets
>      to get the source port used by NA and NB (the external NAT ports EPA
>      and EPB)
> 3. S passes EIPA:EPA to B and EIPB:EPB to A
> 4. A sends a packet to
>      EIPB:EPB.
> 5. NA examines A's packet and creates the following tuple in
>      its translation table: {Source-IP-A, EPA, EIPB, EPB}
> 6. B sends a packet
>      to EIPA:EPA
> 7. NB examines B's packet and creates the following tuple in
>      its translation table: {Source-IP-B, EPB, EIPA, EPA}
> 8. Depending on the
>      state of NA's translation table when B's first packet arrives (i.e.
>      whether the tuple {Source-IP-A, EPA, EIPB, EPB} has been created by
>      the time of arrival of B's first packet), B's first packet is dropped
>      (no entry in translation table) or passed (entry in translation table
>      has been made).
> 9. Depending on the state of NB's translation table when
>      A's first packet arrives (i.e. whether the tuple {Source-IP-B, EPB,
>      EIPA, EPA} has been created by the time of arrival of A's first
>      packet), A's first packet is dropped (no entry in translation table)
>      or passed (entry in translation table has been made).
> 10. At worst, the
>       second packet from A reaches B; at worst the second packet from B
>       reaches A. Holes have been "punched" in the NAT and both hosts can
>       communicate.